# python 3 dictionary comprehension: Advanced

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to convert this to a dict comprehension? How would I know what 
what can be converted and what cannot be?

```
for cpPtr in cpdomains:  
            domainKeys = self.domainSplitter(cpPtr.split(" ")[1])  
                for domainKey in domainKeys:  
                    if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys():  
                        domainAggregator[domainKey] = 
                         int(domainAggregator[domainKey]) + int(cpPtr.split(" ")[0])  
                    else:  
                        domainAggregator[domainKey] = int(cpPtr.split(" ")[0])
```

Comment: Just looking for syntax

Comment: it would be so much easier to help you if you have included sample of the data. Or at least what does the final result look like.

Comment: All of this can be done in a dict comprehension. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: No, you can't really do this with a dict comprehension. In a dictionary comprehension, each key corresponds to one value. Here, you want to collect the sum of the values for a particular key, and the code you have doesn't care whether these values are anywhere near each other. (If they were, there might be a way to gather them up and sum them in one step, and this might make a dict comprehension possible.)

Comment: If you are just looking to simplify this code, turn `domainAggregator` into a `collections.Counter` object and use `Counter.update` with a dictionary of counts.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you can use a dict comprehension, **but you shouldn't**. If you are ready, let's go.

I will start with a little cleanup of your code.

First, I replace `cpPtr.split(" ")[0]` and `cpPtr.split(" ")[1]` with `u` and `v`, where `u,v = cpPtr.split(" ")`. It's a destructuring assignement.

Then I inline the following lines:

```
if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys():
    domainAggregator[domainKey] = int(domainAggregator[domainKey]) + int(u)
else:
    domainAggregator[domainKey] = int(u)
```

into:

```
domainAggregator[domainKey] = int(domainAggregator[domainKey])+int(u) if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys() else int(u)
```

I get now the following code:

```
for cpPtr in cpdomains:
    u,v = cpPtr.split(" ")
    for domainKey in self.domainSplitter(v):
        domainAggregator[domainKey] =  int(domainAggregator[domainKey])+int(u) if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys() else int(u)
```

and I want to turn it in a dict comprehension.

***Now, some little hacks.***

You can't use assignements inside a list or dict comprehension. In order to put that in a list comprehension (and then a dict comprehension, see later), I need to get rid of `=`s:

```
u, v = cpPtr.split(" ")
...
    domainAggregator[domainKey] =  int(domainAggregator[domainKey])+int(u) if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys() else int(u)
```

Becomes:

```
for u, v in [cpPtr.split(" ")]: # this is a singleton
    ...
    domainAggregator.update({domainKey:int(domainAggregator[domainKey])+int(u) if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys() else int(u)}) # I update the dict
```

The code is now:

```
for cpPtr in cpdomains:
    for u,v in [cpPtr.split(" ")]:
        for domainKey in self.domainSplitter(v):
            domainAggregator.update({domainKey:int(domainAggregator[domainKey])+int(u) if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys() else int(u)})
```

Now, I can use a list comprehension to create a side-effect. You just have to insert everything inside square brackets:

```
[domainAggregator.update({domainKey:int(domainAggregator[domainKey])+int(u) if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys() else int(u)}) for cpPtr in cpdomains for u,v in [cpPtr.split(" ")] for domainKey in self.domainSplitter(v)]
```

Okay, after the evaluation of this expression, `domainAggregator` has the expected value, but the list is only a list of `None`s, since `dict.update` returns `None`.

***The following codes are totally insane. Do not try to do this at home!!!***

Is it possible to create a dict comprehension that returns the right value? Yes! You have to create the side effect inside the dict comprehension. Let's try this:

```
# does not work
{k:v for k, v in domainAggregator if len( [domainAggregator.update({domainKey:(int(domainAggregator[domainKey]) if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys() else 0) + int(u)}) for cpPtr in cpdomains for u,v in [cpPtr.split(" ")] for domainKey in self.domainSplitter(v)])>=0}
```

The expression:

```
len([domainAggregator.update({domainKey:(int(domainAggregator[domainKey]) if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys() else 0) + int(u)}) for cpPtr in cpdomains for u,v in [cpPtr.split(" ")] for domainKey in self.domainSplitter(v))>=0
```

is always `True` and you have the desired side-effect. But this side-effect is performed each time you iterate over the items, and you get the infamous `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.

To avoid this, you have to trigger the side effect only once.

```
{k:v for da in [domainAggregator for _ in range(1) if len ([domainAggregator.update({domainKey:(int(domainAggregator[domainKey]) if domainKey in domainAggregator.keys() else 0) + int(u)}) for cpPtr in cpdomains for u,v in [cpPtr.split(" ")] for domainKey in self.domainSplitter(v)])>=0] for k,v in da.items()}
```

The inner list tiggers the side effect and returns the dict, the outer dict comprehension iterates over the items and creates the dict.

**Do not do this!!!**

A MVCE: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRNb4MwDL3zK6ycErVC0O0wIXVStd12mbQjQlMGgUWlASUBrar62xkBCi30Y51PJLHfs/1s8q3@zsRDVYUpVQpeeah5JqjcvmSbXLJvJlR9XkUlFSGLMPEsqC1iMUTZhnLxkadcayaxYmk8h5/OwRhCiILSxVf90V9KpgspwFdaYk4gziRw4AIkFQnDrkMCq2comTTkbocd5i2lmnfcqySRLKE6k0esBjHM37U0qH3I8N6AN5dvbKtgCQbcHhXTANjKHDECRHw3ICcIhqVHMUwD5CmVMR6f8x2yt9d1GCbTwCHXwdnvoYI6eS40vuJBYNa4TOpxRvUYY6li/83hKkGn@RhlIvTiLqE71N3aK1s5qOmtP45o3j6PRowYPVIm8MTVLvKIaoZ3fXkevtngP4rbdBecgyAF2ZMLo9pcF/OyqWbc12A6eefmtyQBeV6C07qvW7CI2lyzTZ3M3rIGuuVhGWeoA0bjtXyqtzKXdd6Ab/4g7H5rj2TcoUfkuc6ekLtxFhdwquoX)

Answer (score 1):

We can't really turn this into a dictionary comprehension, for the reason I explained in my comment, but we can certainly simplify what you have. Using `get()` to access the `domainAggregator` element, we can provide a default of `0` if the key doesn't exist, eliminating that `if` statement.

```
for cpPtr in cpdomains:  
    domainKeys = self.domainSplitter(cpPtr.split(" ")[1])  
    for domainKey in domainKeys:
         domainAggregator[domainKey] = (
             domainAggregator.get(domainKey, 0) + int(cpPtr.split(" ")[0]))
```